# Stopping the execution of R script at the error situation

Tags: r

I want to stop the execution R script if it encounters an error at any point so that it do not give undesirable output.

I have gone through few examples for trycatch but could not get much clarity about how to integrate it in my code. Here is an syntax of the trycatch

```
result = tryCatch({
    expr
}, warning = function(warning-condition) {
    warning-handler-code
}, error = function(error-condition) {
    error-handler-code
}, finally={
    cleanup-code
})
```

Using the above syntax, how can i stop my script from executing furtherstrong text if it encounters an error of any sort.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can look at `stop`

Answer (score 0):

As commented by ahly, if you want to stop execution early you should call stop(). It takes a string as an argument as to why the script was stopped.

As you might know, the code in the finally clause will still be executed.

```
tryCatch(stop("Called stop"), finally = {cat("Still executed")})
```

will give the following

```
Error in tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers) : Called stop
Still executed
```

If you want to learn more, the concept of conditions in R is worth a read. `stop` signals a simpleError condition that is handled internally and leads to exit of the process with an informative message. It could also be given a condition object that gets executed instead.

I myself found the language documentation somewhat scarce in this area, but [Hadley Wickham has written a nice overview](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/beyond-exception-handling.html). If you have worked with a Lisp such as [scheme](http://www.scheme.com/tspl4/exceptions.html) before you will recognize the heritage.